# ExtJS How we can have Export Grid data to Excel / PDF

Tags: extjs4.1

I am currently using ExtJs 4.1.1 version.

I have checked all possible ways to find out Export to Excel functionality, but i didn't find the exact solution on this.

Can you please suggest , Is there any provision to Export the Grid data into Excel , PDF using ExtJs ? 
if yes, Please pass me the correct URL so that I can make my code changes.

Comment: did you get any solution, I need the same. Some have suggested https://github.com/iwiznia/Ext.ux.Exporter but this is on Ext 3.0 and I want something in 4.1

Answer (score 1):

You can try this exporter plugin. 
https://github.com/iwiznia/Ext.ux.Exporter

There other way would be to use a server side component to render CSV or xls output. This may give you better control but you have to hand code all of the pieces. If you are using Java then you can use POI library to create your excel workbook, etc.

Comment: The user asked for Ext 4.1 version. Your suggestion works with Ext 3.0

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide you the code right now, but here's what I do:
 1. build a simple hidden html table with your values from the grid's store.
 2. Find a proper client side export script (using XML and Javascript)
 3. Pass the ID of the hidden table to the function which will build your excel file through XML.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. Just want to know here we have not used ExtJS at all. I want to do using ExtJs, since I have ExtJs Grid ready with me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

[Exporting SDK2 Grid to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029462/exporting-sdk2-grid-to-csv)

code is:

```
Ext.define("GridExporter", {
dateFormat : 'Y-m-d g:i',

exportGrid: function(grid) {
    if (Ext.isIE) {
        this._ieToExcel(grid);

    } else {
        var data = this._getCSV(grid);

        window.location = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(data);
    }
},

_escapeForCSV: function(string) {
    if (string.match(/,/)) {
        if (!string.match(/"/)) {
            string = '"' + string + '"';
        } else {
            string = string.replace(/,/g, ''); // comma's and quotes-- sorry, just loose the commas
        }
    }
    return string;
},

_getFieldText: function(fieldData) {
    var text;

    if (fieldData == null || fieldData == undefined) {
        text = '';

    } else if (fieldData._refObjectName && !fieldData.getMonth) {
        text = fieldData._refObjectName;

    } else if (fieldData instanceof Date) {
        text = Ext.Date.format(fieldData, this.dateFormat);

    } else if (!fieldData.match) { // not a string or object we recognize...bank it out
        text = '';

    } else {
        text = fieldData;
    }

    return text;
},

_getFieldTextAndEscape: function(fieldData) {
    var string  = this._getFieldText(fieldData);

    return this._escapeForCSV(string);
},

_getCSV: function (grid) {
    var cols    = grid.columns;
    var store   = grid.store;
    var data    = '';

    var that = this;
    Ext.Array.each(cols, function(col, index) {
        if (col.hidden != true) {
            data += that._getFieldTextAndEscape(col.text) + ',';
        }
    });
    data += "\n";

    store.each(function(record) {
        var entry       = record.getData();
        Ext.Array.each(cols, function(col, index) {
            if (col.hidden != true) {
                var fieldName   = col.dataIndex;
                var text        = entry[fieldName];

                data += that._getFieldTextAndEscape(text) + ',';
            }
        });
        data += "\n";
    });

    return data;
},

_ieGetGridData : function(grid, sheet) {
    var that            = this;
    var resourceItems   = grid.store.data.items;
    var cols            = grid.columns;

    Ext.Array.each(cols, function(col, colIndex) {
        if (col.hidden != true) {
            console.log('header: ', col.text);
            sheet.cells(1,colIndex + 1).value = col.text;
        }
    });

    var rowIndex = 2;
    grid.store.each(function(record) {
        var entry   = record.getData();

        Ext.Array.each(cols, function(col, colIndex) {
            if (col.hidden != true) {
                var fieldName   = col.dataIndex;
                var text        = entry[fieldName];
                var value       = that._getFieldText(text);

                sheet.cells(rowIndex, colIndex+1).value = value;
            }
        });
        rowIndex++;
    });
},

_ieToExcel: function (grid) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject){
        var  xlApp, xlBook;
        try {
            xlApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); 
            xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
        } catch (e) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'For the export to work in IE, you have to enable a security setting called "Initialize and script ActiveX control not marked as safe" from Internet Options -> Security -> Custom level..."');
            return;
        }

        xlBook.worksheets("Sheet1").activate;
        var XlSheet = xlBook.activeSheet;
        xlApp.visible = true; 

       this._ieGetGridData(grid, XlSheet);
       XlSheet.columns.autofit; 
    }
}});
```

It works perfect also under 4.2.1