# Exporting SDK2 Grid to CSV

Tags: extjs, extjs4, rally

I'd like to export my SDK2 grid to CSV or Excel-- I suspect this code probably exists at Rally somewhere because you can export for example User Stories from a portfolio item to CSV.

Is there a solution to this that people are aware of and can post?

I have found some a [thread of this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?136598-Export-store-to-Excel) on the Sencha website which is entirely client side, but I have been unable to get it to work using a Rally SDK2 grid.

I suspect there may be quite simpler solutions if you only want to go to CSV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Took a look at the example given by Charles above and made this simplified object to export a EXT-JS grid (and so also works with a Rally Grid).

For IE, goes straight to Excel, for other browsers downloads a CSV-- but its a bit rocky using the Data URI approach (file name is not controllable and Excel complains a bit before opening), but its functional.

If somebody who actually knows Javascript wants to post an improvement I'd appreciate it!

```
// Derived and simplified from example on bryntum.com

Ext.define("GridExporter", {
    dateFormat : 'Y-m-d g:i',

    exportGrid: function(grid) {
        if (Ext.isIE) {
            this._ieToExcel(grid);

        } else {
            var data = this._getCSV(grid);

            window.location = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf8,' + encodeURIComponent(data);
        }
    },

    _escapeForCSV: function(string) {
        if (string.match(/,/)) {
            if (!string.match(/"/)) {
                string = '"' + string + '"';
            } else {
                string = string.replace(/,/g, ''); // comma's and quotes-- sorry, just loose the commas
            }
        }
        return string;
    },

    _getFieldText: function(fieldData) {
        var text;

        if (fieldData == null || fieldData == undefined) {
            text = '';

        } else if (fieldData._refObjectName && !fieldData.getMonth) {
            text = fieldData._refObjectName;

        } else if (fieldData instanceof Date) {
            text = Ext.Date.format(fieldData, this.dateFormat);

        } else if (!fieldData.match) { // not a string or object we recognize...bank it out
            text = '';

        } else {
            text = fieldData;
        }

        return text;
    },

    _getFieldTextAndEscape: function(fieldData) {
        var string  = this._getFieldText(fieldData);

        return this._escapeForCSV(string);
    },

    _getCSV: function (grid) {
        var cols    = grid.columns;
        var store   = grid.store;
        var data    = '';

        var that = this;
        Ext.Array.each(cols, function(col, index) {
            if (col.hidden != true) {
                data += that._getFieldTextAndEscape(col.text) + ',';
            }
        });
        data += "\n";

        store.each(function(record) {
            var entry       = record.getData();
            Ext.Array.each(cols, function(col, index) {
                if (col.hidden != true) {
                    var fieldName   = col.dataIndex;
                    var text        = entry[fieldName];

                    data += that._getFieldTextAndEscape(text) + ',';
                }
            });
            data += "\n";
        });

        return data;
    },

    _ieGetGridData : function(grid, sheet) {
        var that            = this;
        var resourceItems   = grid.store.data.items;
        var cols            = grid.columns;

        Ext.Array.each(cols, function(col, colIndex) {
            if (col.hidden != true) {
                console.log('header: ', col.text);
                sheet.cells(1,colIndex + 1).value = col.text;
            }
        });

        var rowIndex = 2;
        grid.store.each(function(record) {
            var entry   = record.getData();

            Ext.Array.each(cols, function(col, colIndex) {
                if (col.hidden != true) {
                    var fieldName   = col.dataIndex;
                    var text        = entry[fieldName];
                    var value       = that._getFieldText(text);

                    sheet.cells(rowIndex, colIndex+1).value = value;
                }
            });
            rowIndex++;
        });
    },

    _ieToExcel: function (grid) {
        if (window.ActiveXObject){
            var  xlApp, xlBook;
            try {
                xlApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); 
                xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
            } catch (e) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'For the export to work in IE, you have to enable a security setting called "Initialize and script ActiveX control not marked as safe" from Internet Options -> Security -> Custom level..."');
                return;
            }

            xlBook.worksheets("Sheet1").activate;
            var XlSheet = xlBook.activeSheet;
            xlApp.visible = true; 

           this._ieGetGridData(grid, XlSheet);
           XlSheet.columns.autofit; 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice.  You'll want to add a test for numbers, too, in the _getFieldText:          like} else if (typeof(fieldData) === "number" ) {
            text = '' + fieldData;
        } else if (!fieldData.match) { 
            // not a string or object we recognize...blank it out
            text = '';
        } else {
            text = fieldData;
        }

Answer (score 1):

You can create an export from a grid by getting the data from the underlying store and creating a [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). You will probably run into problems getting that to work well across different browsers.

You can also see the stuff that [Bryntum](http://www.bryntum.com/examples/scheduler-latest/examples/excelexport/excelexport.html) made here.